# Comparing a string in an array with an input string?

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program that reads a string from a file and split it and take a string from an array and compare it with the string that the user will input.
If they are equal then it will print it but when i use `.contains` in my code it prints a different string of the array that contain the word i write to compare with.
If i use `.equal`, it doesn't work

```
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
   {
        String word;
        System.out.println("Enter word");
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        word=sc.next();

        FileReader file =new FileReader("C:\\Users\\mypc\\Downloads\\ArabicTrans_final.txt");
        BufferedReader reader=new BufferedReader(file);

        String text="";
        String line=reader.readLine();

        while(line !=null)
        {

            text+=line;
            line=reader.readLine();

        }


        String str=text;
        String parts[]=str.split("-");
        int no=0;
        for (int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
        {

            System.out.println(parts[i]);

        }
        for (int i=0;i<parts.length;i++)
        {
            if(parts[i].contains(word))
            {

                System.out.println("num"+i);
                no=i;


            }   

    }
    String newstring[]=parts[no].split(",");

    for (int i=0;i<newstring.length;i++)
    {

        System.out.println("You said : "+newstring[1]);
        break;

    }


}
```

}

inside text file there is some words with arabic translation that i want to show as the result of writing the english word as an input

whats,واتس-
whatsapp,واتس اب -
men,من-
yemen,يمين-
if i write **whats** it will show **whatsapp** not whats

Comment: `if i use .equal it don't work` What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: it would help if you gave us an example of strings that are not working and told us what you got and what you expected to get

Comment: it will show the first element in the array

Comment: ok, the problem is that you continue searching and since using contains, the second word will be accepted which also contains `whats`. Your logic should be different to use `equals` - you must split at `-` and for each combination (`part`)  split at `,` and compare the first token (`newstring[0]`) with the word.